# Analyzing C++ code with implicit constructors and overloaded operators

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operator-overloading, static-analysis

In C++, lots of stuff can be defined that will be executed implicitly in other parts of the code. The most prominent examples are probably:

- Overloaded operators
- Implicit constructor calls

I actually like these features because they make code less verbose. It is also clear that they should be used cautiously, avoiding unexpected or even surprising behaviour.

But how can we analyze code that make use of these features, or even code where we don't know if this is the case?

It is relatively easy to find all references of an explicit function call. In most cases a simple text search is sufficient. For overloaded operators, this obviously will not be very helpful.

Unfortunately, in my experience, IDEs don't provide a lot of help either. (I am mostly working with VS 2015 and 2017.)

Which techniques can be helpful to answer questions like:

- Are there any overloaded operator or implicit constructor calls in a piece of code?
- Where is a given overloaded operator or implicit constructor used in a codebase?

I am aware that you can always step through the code with a debugger but that is often not possible or too time consuming when doing an overall analysis.

Comment: There are static analysis tools which can detect such uses. Not necessarily the cheap ones though. I think Coverity could be configured with such rules IIRC.

Comment: "these features ... make code less verbose" and make it harder to read.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Let's not discuss the pros and cons of these C++ features. That would be interesting but it's off-topic here. Let's just assume we have some existing C++ code making use of these features and need to understand how it works.